# How to establish communication between "AZURE Application Gateway and Linux VM" on azure cloud ?

Tags: azure, deployment, virtual-machine, microservices, azure-application-gateway

Dear All we want to use AZURE Application Gateway to implement SSL in front of our LINUX VM (hosting our node.js microservices).

**As per current configuration:**

-we have same resource group for both application gateway and linux VM.

-both are on the same virtual network but different subnets (as application gateway needs its own subnet).

-Without application gateway i can access my microservices without any issue.

Could somebody please suggest regarding how to establish a communication between application gateway and our microservices hosted on linux VM.

Comment: Hi, what port your service is listening?

Comment: Did you check NSGs? Is the one used by VM opened to the world or to your specific local machine IP?

Answer (score 0):

> -Without application gateway i can access my microservices without any issue.

When your VM is added to a application gateway,  it will not have an impact on the original access. Which your port is your service listening. You could check on linux VM.

```
netstat -ant|grep <port>
```

Please ensure your service is listening and you could access the service with `curl <privateip>:<port>`.

According to your description, I suggest you could add VM's nic to application in backend pool. Like below:

[image]

If your service is not listening on 80, you also need check application gateway HTTP setting.

More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-gateway-portal).

Comment: as Lech Migdal said, you need open your service port on Azure NSG(Inbound rule).

Comment: Dear @walter we are listening on port 80, i have confirmed the same by using the netstat command as suggested by you tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN"

Comment: @GautamMalik Hi, does your VM have public IP, could you assess your service with Public IP address. Add application gateway does not affect it.

Comment: yes my VM has an public IP and i can access the micro-services using this public IP, i have searched further and found that if i have curled using the private IP of this VM i am not getting any response code between the range 200-399(as it requires authentication )....therefore i guess the reason may be that default health probe in application gateway consider this as "unhealthy" because when i used custom probe it gives me status unhealthy when using its private IP, could you please suggest if i need to add another router(path) in the node.js application hosted on linux VM.

Comment: Do you add a heath probe on application gateway? Do you try delete it and test again.

Comment: @GautamMalik Do you select VM or FQDN when you configuration backend pool.

Comment: @GautamMalik It seems your probe's configuration has some mistake. I suggest you could VM's nic as backend pool. For probe, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-probe-portal).